# Problema lectura fichero java (StringIndexOutOfBounnds)

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con la lectura de ficheros, más en concreto a la hora de leer un char, debido a que Java no posee ningún método para encontrarlos al leer los ficheros.

He leído que se puede hacer de esta forma `Scanner.next().charAt();`. 
 Aún así, no hay manera de que me lea el código correctamente. 
Adjunto el código y el fallo que me da para ver si alguien tiene alguna recomendación para que pueda solucionarlo.

```
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Indica el nom del arxiu que vols jugar");
    String nomArxiu = teclado.next();

    Scanner arxiu = new Scanner(new File(nomArxiu));

    int fila = 0;
    int columna = 0;
    int contador = 1;   
    char[][] laberinto =  null;

    arxiu.useDelimiter("");

    while (arxiu.hasNext()) {

    if (contador <= 2) {
        if (contador == 1 || contador == 2) {   
            if (contador == 1) {
                fila = arxiu.nextInt();
            }
            if (contador == 2) {
                columna = arxiu.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        laberinto = new char [fila][columna];

        System.out.println(fila + columna + " contador " + contador);

        for (int i = 0; i < laberinto.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < laberinto[i].length; j++) {

                laberinto[i][j] = arxiu.next().charAt(contador);
                System.out.println(contador);
        }
    }

    }
    contador++;
}
    ImprimirLaberint(laberinto);
    arxiu.close();

    return laberinto;

}
```

También dejo el fallo de la consola:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 3`

Fallo que salta en `laberinto[i][j] =arxiu.next().charAt(contador);`

El archivo a leer tiene este formato `2 2
☺ ·
▒ ♠`

Comment: El StringIndexOutOfBounds es un error que indica que quiere leer en una posición que no existe. En tu caso, cuando hace el charAt(contador), el problema está en que no existe nada en esa posición. Debuga en ese punto a ver. Salut!

Comment: No estas controlando los valores que toma contador, cuando este toma el valor 3 e intenta acceder a la posicion 3 de una linea de 2 posiciones. Logicamente salta el error de que te saliste de los limites de la cadena. Seguramente te pinte el primero segundo y te falle el tercero. No manejas bien el contador.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora me pongo en ello!

Comment: Tienes que inicializar el contador cada vez que leas, e incrementarlo tantas veces como caracteres quieras extraer en la misma lectura

Comment: Muchas gracias maister.

Comment: Denada, una estructura valida seria while (hasNext) {  for (contador = 0; contador < 3 ; contador ++)   ...... Codigo }

Answer (score 1):

antes que nada debes de saber las dimensiones de tus arreglos, pero en la manera de que lo inicializas entendería que es incorrecto ya que se esta creando nuevos cada vez que el contador sea mayor a 2.

```
  Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Indica el nom del arxiu que vols jugar");
    String nomArxiu = teclado.next();

    Scanner arxiu = new Scanner(new File(nomArxiu));

    int fila = 0;
    int columna = 0;
    int contador = 1;   
    char[][] laberinto =  null;

    arxiu.useDelimiter("");

    while (arxiu.hasNext()) {    

           if (contador == 1) {
                fila = arxiu.nextInt();
           }
           if (contador == 2) {
                columna = arxiu.nextInt();
                laberinto = new char [fila][columna];
                System.out.println(fila + columna + " contador " + contador);    
           }


        if (contador>2){    
        for (int i = 0; i < laberinto.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < laberinto[i].length; j++) {
                laberinto[i][j] = arxiu.next().charAt(i+3); //Acuerdate que estas en un ciclo y hasta que termine el ciclo se saldrá y mientras esté aquí el valor de contador seguirá siendo 3 por eso si necesitas escalar sería i+3
                System.out.println(i+3);
           }
        }
        }

    contador++;
}
    ImprimirLaberint(laberinto);
    arxiu.close();

    return laberinto;
}
```

Saludos, espero te sirva, aunque no se porque inicializas el contador a 1.

Comment: Inicializaba a 1 porque tenía entendido, que no como en los arrays o matrices, los ficheros el primer caracter, String... empezaban por 1

Comment: Cierto @CarlosMelladoCardoner más sin embargo el contador no tiene nada que ver con tu archivo, saludos, espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

he encontrado la solución.
Pensando y pensando, he decidido poner en `laberinto[i][j] = arxiu.next().charAt(i+3);` en donde la i+3, he puesto 0, debido a que el scanner del next va saltando posiciones dentro de el fichero, y el "primer puesto" va variando, entonces con poner el 0 se me ha arreglado todo! 
Muchas gracias de todas formas a todos por contestar!